# How to re-prompt loop user input after invalid input range

Tags: python, while-loop

User input range for num of rooms is [1-8]. Invalid input for this should display 'invalid input' and keep reprompt until receive valid input for executing the rest of the program. I've made it so invalid input for services returns and 'invalid service', the same should be done for input of num of rooms.

```
def main():
    small = 60
    medium = 120
    large = 145
    servOne = 40
    servTwo = 80


    numRooms = int(input("Number of rooms in the house?: "))

    while True:
        restart = int(input("Sorry Invalid number of rooms,try again? "))
        if int(numRooms) < 1 or int(numRooms) > 8 in restart:
            continue
            (???)

       




    servType = input("Type of cleaning service requested? (carpet cleaning or window cleaning): ")


    if int(numRooms) <= 2:
        print("Calculating fees for small house...")

        if servType == "carpet cleaning":
            print("Total cost of service:$",(small+servOne))

        elif servType == "window cleaning":
            print("Total cost of service:$",(small+servTwo))

        else:
            print("Sorry! Invalid service input")



    if int(numRooms) >= 3 and int(numRooms) <= 5:
        print("Calculating fees for medium house...")

        if servType == "carpet cleaning":
            print("Total cost of service:$",(medium+servOne))

        elif servType == "window cleaning":
            print("Total cost of service:$",(medium+servTwo))

        else:
            print("Sorry! Invalid service input")



    if int(numRooms) >= 6:
        print("Calculating fees for large house...")

        if servType == "carpet cleaning":
            print("Total cost of service:$",(large+servOne))

        elif servType == "window cleaning":
            print("Total cost of service:$",(large+servTwo))

        else:
            print("Sorry! Invalid service input")
```

main()

Answer (score 1):

just wrap input in a while loop. if valid input is recieved, you end the loop

```
valid_input=False 
while not valid_input:
    i=input("Number of rooms in the house?:")
    inp=int(i)
    if inp in range(1,9):  #(9 is not included)
        valid_input=True 
. 
.
remaining code 
.
.
```

another way to write above ..easier to understand

```
while  1==1:  # repeat loop(all statements below) forever
    i=input("Number of rooms in the house?:")
    inp=int(i)
    if inp in range(1,9):  #(9 is not included)
        break # break out of the forever loop
#end of loop
```

Comment: this works but I don't understand it. is the boolean needed? or can rewrite in standard while loop. Could you explain what the line executes.

Comment: since before we have input there valid_input is obviously false as we have no input
while not valid_input is same as saying while valid_input==False . this while loop will run again and again till valid_input==True.

Comment: Aren't first two lines just same as While True: ?

Comment: I see, I thought 'while not valid_input' meant 'while not (False)'

Comment: yes first time its True... when you receive a valid input, we set valid_input=True and the while loop condition will turn to false..and while loop will not proceed further and continue with code ahead of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

One option (If I assume what you are trying to do) is to have a recursive function instead of a while loop, and call the function again on invalid input:

```py
def Main():
  validnums = [1,2,3]
  i = Input("Please Enter input")
  if int(i) not in validnums:
    Main()
  else:
    ##Do stuff
  Main()
```

By having Main() call Main(), it functions identical to a while loop but you can restart it anytime. I hope this helps.

If you want to avoid recursion:

```py
def Main():
  validnums = [1,2,3]
  While True:
    i = input()
    if int(i) not in validnums:
     break
  Main()
```

This uses a while loop and the function only calls itself when it needs to.

Comment: Why would you do that !!!! thats not an use case for recursion...recursion is heavy on memory... just use a while loop

Comment: my introductory class has not covered recursion yet.

Comment: Don't do recursion for this problem, @geekay 's answer is much more efficient.

Comment: Ok then but the point still stands that you clearly didnt read the issue. The question said "re-prompt" not "break out of" in your example, Eddie here wouldn't be able to call their code again, like asked. You could use a while loop within a function, but you still need it in a function